# Remove unit number in PHP

Tags: php

I want to remove unit numbers in PHP from street addresses. They are always in the format of a pound sign followed by one or more digits, e.g., #45, #6. Would this be easiest to do via regex?

For example:

```
123 Lincoln Street #4, Chicago, IL
```

should become

```
123 Lincoln Street, Chicago, IL
```

Comment: `preg_replace()` use `/#\d+/`

Comment: it can be odd or even

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following regex `/\s+#\d+/`

**\s+** matches one or more spaces
**#\d+** matches a `#` followed by one or more digits

```
$string = "123 Lincoln Street #4, Chicago, IL";

$address = preg_replace('/\s+#\d+/','',$string);

print $address;
```

Will output

```
123 Lincoln Street, Chicago, IL
```